# CLGeocoder returning error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, cllocation, clgeocoder

I am calling this function once I get the addressString:

```
[[self geocoder] geocodeAddressString:addressString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                block(nil, nil, error);
            } else {
                CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks onlyObject];
                block(placemark, self.name, error);
            }
        }];
```

It returns placemarks as nil and error as : 
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"

My address String is retrieved from this dictionary for placeDictionary[@"formatted_address"]:

```
placeDictionary = 
{
"address_components" =     (
            {
        "long_name" = "Palolem Beach";
        "short_name" = "Palolem Beach";
        types =             (
            "natural_feature",
            establishment
        );
    },
            {
        "long_name" = "South Goa";
        "short_name" = "South Goa";
        types =             (
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            political
        );
    },
            {
        "long_name" = Goa;
        "short_name" = GA;
        types =             (
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            political
        );
    },
            {
        "long_name" = India;
        "short_name" = IN;
        types =             (
            country,
            political
        );
    }
);
"adr_address" = "Palolem Beach, <span class=\"region\">Goa</span>";
"formatted_address" = "Palolem Beach, Goa";
geometry =     {
    location =         {
        lat = "15.0099648";
        lng = "74.02321859999999";
    };
    viewport =         {
        northeast =             {
            lat = "15.012671";
            lng = "74.0272093";
        };
        southwest =             {
            lat = "15.0050025";
            lng = "74.0164053";
        };
    };
};
icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png";
id = b286a0f7f047e162b3cab2ab3328ce95d26bdb52;
name = "Palolem Beach";
reference = "CnRwAAAAh2ZORbEpxNv5HnZlQRY_VxKLdvAd16OusSwtBlAKibDFP6roT2idnPvm-XRgMlw3iqUsZujVFrOOns76fK9we3Uddt4b3GgcWZoSqSgoYGtbHh1l5PEL_0VAwaUcswomroA3sjd3dN8lXyBSvafrrxIQONHTpwpn6IvGtYZ12pZ5ixoUENbjRTo3dCrN3aoZTM0k5EPXAjA";
types =     (
    "natural_feature",
    establishment
);
url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Palolem+Beach&ftid=0x3bbe4551d05b02bb:0x1e1bc67d4b0fbbf5";
```

}

Even if I use method:

```
[[self geocoder] geocodeAddressDictionary:placeDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){
```

}];

It returns me the same error.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you calling geocodeAddressString if your dictionary already has the coordinates for the address?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40670608/2033377

Comment: CLGeocoder is not reliable.. Not in India atleast.. Make sure you call google api to get address from lat long. refer my answer in the link above.

Answer (score 19):

You get this error in case Apple's Geocoder knows nothing about provided address.

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clerror/kclerrorgeocodefoundnoresult) code 8 means `kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult`

Answer (score 6):

i think its giving you error because, geocoder is not able to find the location.

check this code , i have modified it

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Palolem Beach, Goa, India" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    if (!error) {

        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {
            NSLog(@"place--%@", [aPlacemark locality]);
            NSLog(@"lat--%f\nlong--%f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude,aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
        }
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"error--%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found recently that when using a US zipcode e.g. 01844 for Massachusetts it won't work if you have the proceeding 0 once I dropped the 0 and just passed 1844 it worked fine.

Comment: I ended up reporting this issue to Apple and it has now been fixed so. you can leave the proceeding 0