# Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)"

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var latLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var longLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var courseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var altLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!

    var manager:CLLocationManager!
    var userLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.distanceFilter = 50
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        println(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)

        var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        latLabel.text = "\(latitude)"
        var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        longLabel.text = "\(longitude)"

        var course:CLLocationDirection = userLocation.course
        courseLabel.text = "\(course)"

        var speed:CLLocationSpeed = userLocation.speed
        speedLabel.text = "\(speed)"

        var altitude:CLLocationAccuracy = userLocation.altitude
        altLabel.text = "\(altitude)"


        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {

                println(error)

            } else {
                if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks?[0] as CLPlacemark) {
                    println(p)
                }
            }

        })



        //println("Location = \(locations)")
        println(locations)
    }


}
```

I keep getting this error Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)" when I try to get the users closest address. I am not sure what the issue is, can anybody see what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: [KCLError 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCLErrorNetwork) is `kCLErrorNetwork`, described as "The network was unavailable or a network error occurred." May be silly but have you checked your network connection?

Answer (score 7):

That's a network error, CLGeocoder needs a working network connection in order to reverse geocode a location, according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html).

Also, CLGeocoder will throttle geocoding requests, returning that same error if you exceed the request rate, this is also documented in the class reference.

Comment: For the sake of completeness The "maximum rate" mentioned in the docs is not specified. While Apple suggests 1 geocoding per minute per app, I managed to do somewhat 100 geocodings one after the other...

Comment: @Sasho: sure, but 100 is not a guaranteed rate. If the server has too much requests, it _will_ throttle down your responses. I've seen this more than once when abusing the service.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can pass lat long to this [google api](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.017615,72.856164&sensor=true) and get all fields related to address depending on the "types" in the json

Answer (score 0):

Maybe permission is (denied)
this easy but make a headache ;