# Xamarin.Essentials Geocoding.PlacemarksAsync throws error in iOS using Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm using Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(lat, lon) method of Xamarin.Essentials to get placemarks. But when I trying to get placemarks from lat long, It throws following error in iOS simulator. It works find in Android emulator and in android physical device too.

Error:

```
NSErrorException Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain code=2 "(null)" at Xamarin.Essentials.GeoCoding.PlatformGetPlacemarksAsync
```

I have added location permissions in info.plist. My project configurations are:

Xamarin.forms: 4.5.0.725

Xamarin.Essentials: 1.6.1

XCode: 12.2

Simulator: iPhone 8+ 14.4

Same code works fine in Android. Hope for solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [open and set the location in the simulator](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/simulating-location-in-ios)?

That's maybe a network or the frequency of geocoding requests problem, you'd better check it.

As

KCLError 2 is kCLErrorNetwork, described as "The network was unavailable or a network error occurred."

And

CLGeocoder will throttle geocoding requests, returning that same error if you exceed the request rate.

you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087660/error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-2-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-kclerr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867422/kclerrordomain-error-2-after-geocoding-repeatedly-with-clgeocoder) page for more details.

If that still not work, you can try it on the real device.